# Trigger Animation in PowerPoint

Tags: vba, powerpoint, powerpoint-2007

I have Microsoft Office PowerPoint 2007. I want to make it so that it will start a specific animation when I press the F4 key. I currently have the following:

```
Sub DoAnimation()

End Sub

Sub auto_open()
    Application.OnKey "{F4}","DoAnimation"
End Sub
```

So how would I start the animation in the DoAnimation sub?

Comment: OnKey is not available in PowerPoint. Also, you cannot trigger a specific animation programmatically. You could trigger the next slide or next animation by executing Slideshowwindows(1).View.Next

Comment: Thank you very much. I think I've now found an alternative way of achieving my goal.